# Podcasts connect "Can't parse your feed"

Tags: itunes, podcasts, rss

I'm trying to submit a podcast to Podcasts Connect and I get the error

> Can’t parse your feed.

With a status of

> Failed Validation

[This](http://superculpodcast.com/RSS) is my feed. I've used multiple rss validators (Here's the list)

- [Podba.se](https://podba.se/validate/?url=http://superculpodcast.com/RSS)
- [Castfeed validator](https://castfeedvalidator.com/?url=http://superculpodcast.com/RSS)
- [W3C rss validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/)

Among others. Every validator says that my rss is good or has nothing bigger than a few warnings, but whenever the Apple validator at Podcasts Connect gives this error I mentioned saying it cant parse the feed, but not any further description. Any Idea of what could my problem be or where is my mistake?

UPDATE: Just as a test I tried to submit it to Spotify and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of trial and error I found what was causing the trouble.

My feed had this line at the very begining:

```
standalone="yes"
```

Inside the `<?xml ?>` declaration.
Removing that from the feed fixed it for both Apple Podcasts and Spotify.